# Display Date picker for ionic

Tags: angularjs, date, ionic-framework, datepicker

I need date picker for my hybrid mobile app, i develop an application with ionic framework and i want to display Date picker by clicking on a button, i don't want to choose the normal way like : < input type = "date">

Thank you for helping me,

Comment: Check this one, https://github.com/katemihalikova/ion-datetime-picker, you can find the instruction in readme. You can find a lot of datepicker modules on the Internet, just google for it.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you do not want to use `< input type = "date">`? I use it in few applications, both Android and iOS, without any problems.

Comment: Thanks, in fact i searched a lot in google..., but :) i don't understand how to implement the date picker in my project, it's a bit difficult for me

Comment: Tomislav Stankovic : i need the professional view for web

Comment: Check the ionic-datepicker, which is a bower component, which can be used in any Ionic framework's application: https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker